# How to Move Object when device orientation get changed?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app, in which i have `X object` and when `device orientation` get changed, the `object should get changed in same direction`.

for example, I have an X Object.

```
Y
|
|
|
|
|
|___________X
```

Want to move `X object` in `same direction` as `device Orientation` `get changed` ?

I am not getting how to do it ?

Please suggest me , How could i do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use viewDidLayouSubviews, see a sample:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
     ....
    }
    else if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
     .....
    }
    else ...
}
```